# How to wait for angular provider inside .config to fully load

Tags: angularjs, config, wait, angular-providers

I'm setting a value to the url variable inside the .provider in services.js from .config in app.js

Services.js:

```
function BaseUrl(url) {
    this.url = url;
}

angular.module('eter.services', [])
    .provider("baseurl", [function () {
        var url = null;

        this.setUrl = function (textString) {
            url = textString;
        };

        this.$get = [function () {
            return new BaseUrl(url);
        }];
    }]);
```

app.js (inside a json request in .config):

```
baseurlProvider.setUrl(schoolObj.school_domain);
```

When I try to use the baseurl provider's get method inside a controller I get null (the startvalue) because the json request inside .config in app.js is too slow.

controllers.js:

```
... 
$http.get(baseurl.url +'eter-app-api/'+ apikey +'&startpage=1'). 
...
```

How can I speed up the process/slow down the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can bootstrap angular after getting base url from server:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['eter.services'])
    .config(['baseUrl', 'baseurlProvider', function (baseUrl, baseurlProvider) {
        baseurlProvider.setUrl(baseUrl);
    }]);

$.getJSON('/getBaseUrl', function (baseUrl) {
    app.value('baseUrl', baseUrl);
    angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
});
```

Comment: I do the baseurlProvider.setUrl(baseUrl) inside the json request which is inside .config. Can I bootstrap right after I've set the url?

Comment: @TheWorldyn angular is already bootstrapped when config code executes, so as shown above, you shall get data before bootstrapping.